Weird parallel route behavior in Next Js
I am getting a behavior with parallel which seems inconsistent,
I have 3 routs home a modal overlay and a cart overlay. the cart and the modal are in their own slot, the modal has a catch-all route and the cart has a default.js both returning null. on soft navigation, everything works smooth but on hard navigation I get the following behavior:
home ->modal ->refresh -> router.back -- works as expected
home -> cart -> refresh ->modal - > refresh -> router.back -- works as exepceted
home -> cart -> modal - > refresh -> router.back -- url changes but the modal is being renderd.
Any ideas what is going on?

